# Difference between \defbeamertemplate* and \setbeamertemplate

Tags: beamer

Can somebody explain what the difference between `\defbeamertemplate*` and `\setbeamertemplate` is?

Specifically:

```
\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{default}[1][]
```

This code is from the default [beamer theme](http://mirror.unl.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/base/themes/inner/beamerinnerthemedefault.sty).

What I do not understand:

1. What does the word `default` do? Sometimes it can be named something different.
2. What does the `1` part mean?
3. Why is `\setbeamertemplate` not used instead for everything?

Comment: If I'm not wrong, in your example `\defbeamertemplate` defines a template for `title page` named `default`. You can define as much as templates you want with different names. Once defined you can select which one to apply with `\setbeamertemplate`.

Answer (score 2):

From the [user manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf), page 169:

> \setbeamertemplate {⟨element name⟩}[⟨predefined option⟩]⟨args⟩In the
>   simplest case, if no ⟨predefined option⟩ is given, the ⟨args⟩ must be
>   a single argument and the text of the template ⟨element name⟩ is setup
>   to be this text. Upon later invocation of the template by the command
>   \usebeamertemplate this text is used.
>
> [...]
>
> If you specify a ⟨predefined option⟩ ,
>   this command behaves slightly differently. In this case, someone has
>   used the command \defbeamertemplate to predefine a template for you.
>   By giving the name of this predefined template as the optional
>   parameter ⟨predefined option⟩ , you cause the template ⟨element name⟩
>   to be set to this template.

Comment: I've read the manual, but from my reading of the manual they seem to be the same thing then? I'm more curious as to what the [1][] part does, if you know?

Comment: The difference is, as Ignasi said, that the first one sets the template whereas the second one defines one. if the template is not defined you cannot set it... Then you have \usebeamertemplate which seems to do the same as \setbeamertemplate, but I guess it is for local use. I use \defbeamertemplate when I create style files.